# how to make this selector in the image with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, selector, screen-brightness

[selector image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9HGI.jpg)

this selector should change the brightness, so what widget in Flutter should I use and how to change the brightness??

Comment: Please write a better title for your question

Answer (score 1):

this package, [sleek_circular_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/sleek_circular_slider) is similar to your need:

```
final slider = SleekCircularSlider(
                      appearance: CircularSliderAppearance(),
                      onChange: (double value) {
                        //Change your brightness value
                      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the following permissions to your Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/screen) plugin, add screen as a dependency in your pubspec.yaml file.

```
// Import package
import 'package:screen/screen.dart';

// Get the current brightness:
double brightness = await Screen.brightness;

// Set the brightness:
Screen.setBrightness(0.5);

// Check if the screen is kept on:
bool isKeptOn = await Screen.isKeptOn;

// Prevent screen from going into sleep mode:
Screen.keepOn(true);
```

Find an example [here](https://pub.dev/packages/screen/example) on how to implement this plugin.